# Contenteditable Div (Fixed Height) with Scrollbar

Tags: css

```
<div class="col span_1_of_2" contenteditable="true" style="max-height:   410px" overflow: "true">
```

Currently, text in div fils area (410px h). I'd like to add more text:
a) without expanding the div height
b) have 'extra' text visible by scroll

Currently, the div stays set at 410px; but scroll effect does not take (and texts spills outside div). See screenshot.

[image: [Div w/ No Scroll-But Text Overflow]]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_2" contenteditable="true" id="comments">
```

CSS:

```
#comments {
    max-height: 410px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: DFC: I tried your suggestion a number of ways.
1) inline div tag | inside style= and alone
2) in <style></style> area of header

No scroll appeared. If attributes are both in <style> and <div>, would that be a problem. (Just curious.)

Comment: @RafikiCai want to set up a jsfiddle for it so I can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Add overflow-y: auto; max-height: 410px; to your right hand side column. Give it an id or something, like #comments and target that with css.

Comment: @RafikiCai I've modified the answer

Comment: DFC: 1) in <style> tag I created #scriptcontent { overflow-y: auto; max-height: 410px; } 2) In col 2 <div> tag I set id= "scriptcontent".  Div still goes beyond 410px. Where did I misstep?  iamced.com/reviews

Comment: @RafikiCai I can't see any changes or new id's on that link you sent http://www.iamced.com/reviews/ - the CSS hasn't been applied?

Comment: Finally. I 'thought' I was logged in and making real edits, but they were fantasy edits. LOL | DFC, you rock, rock. | A related question: do you know of any web resources, that would a) allow the script box to be edited (in the browser) and changes be saved on the server and b) notifications of changes (w/ actual edits) be pushed via email or SMS? | Again, thanks for your helping hand.

Comment: @RafikiCai you'll need to send the content to your server via AJAX https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/saving-contenteditable-content-changes-as-json-with-ajax/ then use something like Twilio to send SMS notifications. You'll definitely need some programming knowledge to do this, the simplest probably being PHP in this case.